# Modifying horizontal bar size in subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a horizontal bar at the bottom of each pie chart in a figure. I am using subplots to achieve this, but I don't know how to customise the subplots with the horizontal bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(28, 11)

countery=0
for y in range(1,15):
    counterx=0
    
    for x in range(1,12):
        axes[countery,counterx].pie([70,20])

        axes[countery+1,counterx].barh('a',40,height=1)
        axes[countery+1,counterx].barh('a',60,left=40,height=1)
        axes[countery+1,counterx].axis('off')
        
        counterx=counterx+1

    countery=countery+2

plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to change the size of the horizontal bar so it doesn't take all the horizontal space. and make it look smaller overall. I would like it to look something like this for each:

[image]

I've tried changing `wspace` and `hspace` in
`plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=0.2, hspace=5)` but no luck. Any help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`box_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect) of the bar charts. Also, using 14 rows with [`subgridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.SubplotSpec.html?highlight=subgridspec#matplotlib.gridspec.SubplotSpec.subgridspec)s of 2 rows each is slightly faster than the 28 rows gridspec:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(14, 11)

for y in range(gs.nrows):
    for x in range(gs.ncols):
        ax_pie, ax_bar = gs[y, x].subgridspec(2, 1, height_ratios=[5, 1]).subplots()
        ax_pie.pie([70,20])
        ax_bar.barh('a', 40, height=1)
        ax_bar.barh('a', 60, left=40, height=1)
        ax_bar.set_box_aspect(1/5)
        ax_bar.axis('off')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Tidied the loop a bit (removed the counters - you've used a `for` loop like a `while` loop - we can use the iterated variables directly). Other than that, the below should work. First, using `figsize` make the output taller than wide, as we expect each subplot to be taller than it is wide as per your goal image. Then set the ratios of the heights of each subplot by whether it is even (a pie) or odd (a bar). Fiddle with the `4` and `1` ratios in `hr` to get what looks right for you, and let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h = 14
w = 11

hr = [4 if i % 2 == 0 else 1 for i in range(h*2)]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(28, 11, figsize=(6, 12), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':hr})

for y in range(0,h*2,2):
    for x in range(w):
        axes[y,x].pie([70,20])

        axes[y+1,x].barh('a',40,height=1)
        axes[y+1,x].barh('a',60,left=40,height=1)
        axes[y+1,x].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Produces

[image]